# external smtp.config from Web.config does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I extracted `<smtp />` settings from Web.config to an external smtp.config. And now when I run the application I get an error `The SMTP host was not specified.`

Web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.net>
       <mailSettings>
          <smtp configSource="smtp.config" />
       </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
</configuration>
```

smtp.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<smtp from="name@email.com">
  <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\_TempEmail"/>
</smtp>
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**

A fuller version of Web.config.

```
<configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <system.net>
        <mailSettings>
          <smtp configSource="smtp.config" />
        </mailSettings>
      </system.net>
      <connectionStrings>
        <!-- connection strings here -->
      </connectionStrings>
      <appSettings>
        <!-- app settings here -->
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
      <!-- more settings here -->
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
      <!-- more settings here-->
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
      <!-- more settings here -->
      </runtime>
      <entityFramework>
      <!-- more settings here -->
      </entityFramework>
  </configuration>
```

**Edit 2:**

The correct smtp.config that works is below.

I was missing `deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<smtp from="name@email.com" deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
  <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\_TempEmail"/>
</smtp>
```

Comment: Does that same configuration work when you include it directly in the web.config? (Since your question implies that it does not; just verifying)

Comment: Yes, silly me. I copied this from my other project and assumed everything just works. I was missing a `deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory"` from `<smtp />` in the smtp.config. Thank you.